# How to kill proccess running more than x seconds by process name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill

I would like to kill all chrome processes that are running for more than 30 seconds.

At the moment i'm using this command below, but it kills all chrome processes regardless:

```sh
killall -9 chrome
```

Comment: Instead of searching for the processes after starting the browser, why don't you use the `timeout` utility when you start the browser? Maybe that doesn't work with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can display all PIDs that verify your execution time criterion:

```
 > \ps -eo pid,etimes,args | \
 sed -nE 's/^\ +//;s/\ +/ /g;/chrome/p' | \
 cut -d' ' -f1,2 | while read -r -a ARRAY; do 
     [ "${ARRAY[1]}" -gt 30 ] && printf "%s\n" ${ARRAY[0]}
 done
```

Once satisfied that this yields what you want, just replace the `printf`command with `kill -9`, like so:

```
 > \ps -eo pid,etimes,args | \
 sed -nE 's/^\ +//;s/\ +/ /g;/chrome/p' | \
 cut -d' ' -f1,2 | while read -r -a ARRAY; do 
     [ "${ARRAY[1]}" -gt 30 ] && kill -9 ${ARRAY[0]}
 done
```

Not part of your question, but you may want to think about sending a soft/polite kill `SIGTERM` signal (with just `kill ...` or equivalently with `kill -15 ...`) instead of sending a hard kill `SIGKILL` signal (with `kill -9 ...`), depending on why exactly and in what conditions you want to terminate the Chrome processes in question. For more on the subject, see the difference [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/sigterm-vs-sigkill/) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Both killall and pkill have the concept of an "older than" selector.

```
killall 30s chrome
pkill --older 30 chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,args |grep chrome
```

`etimes` will display the elapsed time since the process was started in seconds.

Then:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```